# How to do MATLAB's mnrnd in R

Tags: r, matlab

--

Hello everyone, in MATLAB,

```
mnrnd([10 4 8]', [0.1 0.3 0.2 0.4; 0.15 0.65 0.05 0.15; 0.4 0.1 0.25 0.25])
```

will generate a matrix like

```
 0     2     3     5

 1     3     0     0

 2     1     1     4
```

How can I get similar result in R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is to create multinomial random numbers try `rmultinomial` from `multinomRob` or you can try from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915668/draw-a-huge-sample-1e09-from-a-multinomial-distribution-with-sample)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Akrun. Seems `multinomRob` cannot do this, but `rmultinomial` from `combinat` can do the same thing.

Comment: In base, if `m` is your matrix of probabilities, `t(sapply(seq(3), function(i){rmultinom(1, c(10, 4, 8)[i], m[i, ])}))`. If you have a list instead of a matrix, `mapply` would work neatly.

Comment: Thanks Alistaire, it's perfect for me.